# zoom and pan effect in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have made a flash world map (Continents Wise). What i want is that, when i click on any continent, it should zoom out to the full area and the area should also be floatable so that it can be panned with mouse.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon clicking on a continent, load a larger continent image, scaled down to be the same size as the initial continent, right on top of the continent that was clicked on.  Then tween the continent up to full scale where you can use keyboard events or mouse events to pan the image around.  If you expect the interaction to be quick and seamless you might want to load the larger images at runtime to have them available immediately upon user interaction.  Another thing to consider is image quality.  You'll have to use bitmap smoothing to make the scaling look reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

For panning you can use any of the oxylus panning component
Visit http://www.oxylusflash.com/search/tag/Pan?page=3